# C# Reflection GetType() exception

Tags: c#, reflection, appdomain

I got strange error and don't know why.

```
Type names passed to Assembly.GetType() must not specify an assembly.
```

The strange thing is I don't use method GetType() by myself. It is caused by following line:

```
var domainCommunicator = (DomainCommunicator)dmn.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(DomainCommunicator).FullName, "DomainCommunicator");
```

domainCommunicator inherits from MarshalByRefObject. It's public but when i change it into private i get the exception that the assembly cannot be loaded. When I create additional project in my solution and have completly external .dll nothing changes. Probably because I must have reference to the main project in my new AppDomain.

Best thing for me is to skip the DomainCommunicator class in reflection. It should be private and that's it. What caused the exception exactly?

Comment: Is the `dmn` object an AppDomain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`AppDomain.CreateAndUnwrap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx) expects the [`Assembly.FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.fullname.aspx) and [`Type.FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx):

```
public Object CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    string assemblyName,
    string typeName
)
```

The correct usage would be:

```
var type = typeof(DomainCommunicator);
var domainCommunicator = (DomainCommunicator)dmn.CreateAndUnwrap(type.Assembly.FullName,
                                                                 type.FullName);
```

Example Values:

`Assembly.FullName`

- `AssemblyName, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

`Type.FullName`

- `Namespace+ClassName`

Comment: So obvious. Of course, after managing serialization exception it worked. AppDomains are so evil:) Thank you very much